# Dedicated domain for admin backend

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have Symfony2.8 application installed on my server. To make things easier, let's assume that in `/very-long-path/web` directory. I also have domain for this directory - eg. `example.com`. Page at `example.com` is accessible by all my users. Application has also backend for admins at `example.com/admin`. I think this is common configuration for many webpages.

What I want to do is:

1. Buy second domain eg. `admin-of-example.com`.
2. Disable access to the `example.com/admin` (or configure redirect to admin-of-example.com)
3. Make backend for admins accessible **only** via this second domain.

Is it possible and how? I completely don't know how to do that? Probably `mod_rewrite`?

What may be important? Symfony base on fron controller, therefore `example.com/admin` not directs to real folder - there is no `/very-long-path/web/admin` directory. Frontend for users and backend for admins are parts of one application, therefore I cannot move backend to other hosting/domain physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict routes to be matched only when the request is for a particular hostname: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html